# Get the updated html content of asp:Literal or div in server side when modified by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I currently have an series of html code that pass to the literal asp control.

```
Labelhighlight.Text = <strong>foo sample</strong>;
```

On my View here are my controls used

```
<div id="highlightedtext" class="well" runat="server"> 
  <asp:Literal ID="Labelhighlight" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough">
  </asp:Literal>
  </asp:Label>
</div>
```

then on my client side I wrapped a string using jquery that results to

```
<div id="highlightedtext" class="well">
  <string>foo <span id='test'>sample</span> </strong>
</div>
```

then on my server side I should get the updated html content on button click
here's the code behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var test = RenderControl(Labelhighlight);
}

public string RenderControl(System.Web.UI.Control ctrl)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
  HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

  ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

I only  get the previous html string which is `<strong>foo sample</strong>`. I also tried getting the html content of div but the following error occur: **Cannot get inner content of because the contents are not literal**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like there may be some syntax errors in your HTML. Please check your ASP code and HTML code. Please also check your browser console for any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the code where I insert span tag around a text using jquery is working on the browser. it just don't update the content around the literal control. maybe I need a jquery that save the code on literal I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: When you are working in jQuery, this is Client Side changes only, they are not posted back to the Server Side unless programmed to do so. So, how does the server know that the literal content has changed? It has already parsed it and sent it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to save the content to a hidden div without using runat="server" then get the content in my server side using request form, code as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="div_content" name="div_content" />
```

then on my jquery

```
   function SaveToHidden() {

                     var content = document.getElementById("highlightedtext").innerHTML;

                     document.getElementById("div_content").value = content;
                 };
    </script>
```